# I need to create a Datalog Query based off two Tables?

Tags: datalog

The Datalog rule below for none_of_manufacturer was intended to
list those aircraft manufacturers for which the airline has no aircraft in
its fleet. The fragment of Datalog below, however, does not do what it
was intended to do.

```
none_of_manufacturer(Man) :- aircraft_type(Model, Man, _),
¬ model_in_fleet(Model).
model_in_fleet(Model) :- aircraft(_, Model, _).
```

what can i do to the above query to fix it?

I thought of one suggestion:

```
none_of_manufacturer(Man) :- aircraft_type(Model, Man, _),
¬ model_in_fleet(Model, Man).
model_in_fleet(Model, Man) :- aircraft(_, Model, _), aircraft_type(_ ,Man, _).
```

What do you guys think? I have attached the tables below

```
        aircraft
---------------------------      
|  reg  |  model  |  miles  |  
|---------------------------|
|G-CWQS |737-400C | 2945321 |
|G-FDWC |737-400  | 506834  |
|G-FXDC |737-400  | 34760   |
|G-KLSD |737-400  | 590     |
|G-UGHJ |380      | 4544    |
-----------------------------
```

```
            aircraft_type
-------------------------------------
|model   | manufacturer|  no_engines |
-------------------------------------|
|727     | Boeing      |    3        |
|737-200 | Boeing      |    2        |
|737-400 | Boeing      |    2        |
|737-400C| Boeing      |    2        |
|737-500 | Boeing      |    2        |
|380     | Airbus      |    4        |
|747     | Boeing      |    4        |
|MD11    | MD          |    3        |
--------------------------------------
```

Update

I have discovered a technique which could solve the problem. Considering the original query returned the manufacture of models not in the aircraft table which in this case would be Boing for the following missing planes (727,737-200,737,500)  and MD for (MD11). Our ultimate result is MD as we do not have a MD plane so

```
Existing_manufacturer(Man):-aircraft_type(Model,Man,-),aircraft(_,Model,).
returns the manufacturer of existing planes Boing and Airbus.

Now if we were to use the previous query in the original

none_of_manufacturer(Man) :- aircraft_type(_ ,Man, _),
¬ Existing_manufacturer(Man).

Will calculate the difference and return only MD.
```

Comment: What are your expectations? Reading your rules, I would expect the value of none_of_manufacturer(Man) to be {Boeing, Airbus, MD}.

Comment: Basically it's meant to return the Manufacturer from which it has no plains from, so just MD.

Answer (score 0):

You already solved your own problem, but to explain precisely why your original query did not work:

```
none_of_manufacturer(Man) :-
   aircraft_type(Model, Man, _),
   !model_in_fleet(Model).
```

The predicate will contain every Man for which there exists *some* Model that is not in the fleet.

It's interesting that just the presence of the Model variable can cause this kind of confusion. To avoid this, I always like to just model things very explicitly so that your logic is obviously correct.

The rule that you were writing above in a simpler form would be:

```
missing(Man) :-
   manufacturer(Man),
   !manufacturer_in_fleet(Man).
```

Now how to compute those?

```
model_in_fleet(Model) :-
   aircraft(_, Model, _).

manufacturer_in_fleet(Man) :-
   aircraft_type(Model, Man, _),
   model_in_fleet(Model).

manufacturer(Man) :-
   aircraft_type(_, Man, _).
```

Comment: Thanks allot Martin. Your right, yours looks allot cleaner. Thanks again for your input

Comment: @user3255780: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)